# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pssh'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pssh, parallel-ssh

I am using python3.9 and I got the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pssh'`

on trying to use the library as follows: -

`from pssh.clients import ParallelSSHClient`.

I tried installing `pssh` as follows: -

`pip install pssh` (inside a virtual environment)

but the error didn't go away.

Which library has to be installed to make the above import work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing [parallel-ssh](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-ssh/) will help in this case:

`pip install parallel-ssh`.

[pssh](https://pypi.org/project/pssh/) seems to work only till python3.2.